# 3 div's nested in div centered but acting as if margin or padding when none

Tags: css, center, html

I have three div's nested in another div.  The three div's have css display:inline:block so that they act as if floating but there is a gap between each div as if there is a margin or padding on them.

Here is HTML:

```
    <div id="lowerContentHeaderContainer">
      <div id="borderLowerContentL"></div><!-- borderLowerContentL -->
      <div id="textLowerContentM">some title goes here</div><!-- textLowerContent -->
      <div id="borderLowerContentR"></div><!-- borderLowerContentR -->
    </div><!-- lowerContentHeaderContainer -->
```

Here is CSS:

```
#lowerContentHeaderContainer {
position:relative;
width:746px;
text-align:center;
}
#borderLowerContentL {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:6px;
height:39px;
background-image:url(img/SideBar_MiddleTitle_Area_01.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border:1px solid #000;
}
#textLowerContentM {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
height:39px;
background-image:url(img/SideBar_MiddleTitle_Area_02.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
border:1px solid #000;
}
#borderLowerContentR {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:6px;
height:39px;
background-image:url(img/SideBar_MiddleTitle_Area_04.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

[image]

Borders have been added around the nested div's so you can see what I am talking about.  Also, the center div is not aligned horizontally like it should be.

Any ideas how to get rid of the space between the divs and align the center div properly?

Answer (score 0):

the browser will see the linebreaks as spaces unless they are floated.

html

```
<div id="lowerContentHeaderContainer"><div id="borderLowerContentL">&nbsp;</div><div id="textLowerContentM">some title goes here</div><div id="borderLowerContentR">&nbsp;</div></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kudoslabs/CTpYH/